# VB.NET Custom Complex Sort in least possible steps

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, sorting, artificial-intelligence, shortest-path

I also want to say I don't care which solution the algorithm generates as I know there is plenty of solutions for the same amount of moves.

I just want any solution that is the least possible moves for the current puzzle.

Thank you. There isn't really any pattern I can think off all I know is lowest numbers must go in front and biggest numbers must go in back, but the trick is it moves 2 numbers at once one from the front and one from the back together like Sort with a more modifiable stack together.

This game contains only 2 moves..

- Left Cyclic Rotation At Any Offset (except the last byte) Right
- Cyclic Rotation At Any Offset (except the last byte)

Here is the function code for that

```
Public Function CyclicRotationOffset(ByVal data() As Byte, ByVal beginOffset As Integer, ByVal leftDirection As Boolean) As Byte()

    'Left Direction = true
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'Shifted cyclically rotation If [a, b, c] then [b, c, a]
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'Left Direction = false
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'Shifted cyclically rotation If [a, b, c] then [c, a, b]
    '--------------------------------------------------------

    If beginOffset = UBound(data) Then
        'last byte cannot do anything.
        Return data
    End If

    Dim newdata() As Byte
    ReDim newdata(UBound(data))

    If leftDirection = True Then
        newdata(UBound(newdata)) = data(beginOffset) '1st element will be last.
        For i = beginOffset To UBound(data) - 1
            newdata(i) = data(i + 1)
        Next i
    Else
        newdata(beginOffset) = data(UBound(data)) 'last element will be first.
        For i = beginOffset + 1 To UBound(data)
            newdata(i) = data(i - 1)
        Next i
    End If

    If beginOffset > 0 Then
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, newdata, 0, beginOffset)
    End If

    Return newdata
End Function
```

Here are two examples
---------------------------------------------- 
Data, Solved in 6 moves with brute force (and function).
2, 7, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9
----------------------------------------------
Brute Forced Rotations
3 Lefts, 3 Rights
----------------------------------------------
1, Left
2, Left
0, Right
6, Right
3, Left
5, Right
---------------------------------------------
2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7
2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 1
1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7
1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 <- Final one produces the sorted answer
----------------------------------------------

**Here is a harder example (this one stumped me)**
Solved in 7 moves (with brute force)
data=
**3, 9, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 8**
answer=
**1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9**

**4 Lefts, 3 Rights**
moves taken
6, Left
0, Right
3, Left
7, Right
2, Left
3, Left
1, Right

3, 9, 7, 4, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1
1, 3, 9, 7, 4, 2, 5, 6, 8
1, 3, 9, 4, 2, 5, 6, 8, 7
1, 3, 9, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8
1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Here is my code that finds the 6 move solution for the first puzzle, But for the second puzzle it doesn't handle it right so the solution itakes **14 moves** instead of the **optimal 7 moves**.

```
Public Structure OffsetMove
    Dim moveId As Byte
    Dim randomOffset As Byte
    Public Sub New(ByVal moveId As Byte, ByVal randomOffset As Byte)
        Me.moveId = moveId
        Me.randomOffset = randomOffset
    End Sub
End Structure

Public Function SortDataCyclic(ByVal data() As Byte) As List(Of OffsetMove)
    Dim answer() As Byte
    ReDim answer(UBound(data))
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, answer, 0, data.Length)
    Array.Sort(answer)
    Dim newdata() As Byte
    ReDim newdata(UBound(data))
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, newdata, 0, data.Length)

    Dim i As Long = 0
    Dim j As Long = 0
    Dim k As Long = 0
    Dim l As Long = 0
    Dim solutionCount As Integer = 0
    Dim movesTaken As New List(Of OffsetMove)
    Debug.Print("---------------------------------------------")

    Dim sortedPairs As New List(Of Byte)

    While j < 8
        If sortedPairs.Count >= 3 Then
            'Insertion right cyclic rotations go here
            While l < 9
                k = 0
                While k < 9
                    If newdata(k) > newdata(8) Then Exit While
                    k += 1
                End While
                If k = 9 Then
                    'fully sorted already, nothing left to insert.
                    Exit While
                End If
                newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, k, False)
                movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(1, k))
                printDebug(newdata)

                l += 1
            End While

            'Exit the while, everything is sorted.
            Exit While
            '1, 2, x, x, x, x
        ElseIf j + 1 < 9 AndAlso _
            newdata(j + 1) = (newdata(j) + 1) Then
            sortedPairs.Add(j)
            j += 2
            '1, x, 2, x, x, x
        ElseIf j + 2 < 9 AndAlso _
            newdata(j + 2) = (newdata(j) + 1) Then
            newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, (j + 1), True)
            movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(0, (j + 1)))
            printDebug(newdata)
            j = 0
            'No pair pattern at all.
        Else
            newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, j, True)
            movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(0, j))
            printDebug(newdata)
        End If
    End While
    Return movesTaken
End Function

Public Sub printDebug(ByVal data() As Byte)
    Debug.Print(data(0) & ", " & data(1) & ", " & data(2) & ", " & data(3) & ", " & data(4) & ", " & data(5) & ", " & data(6) & ", " & data(7) & ", " & data(8))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code, and came up with different result sets than you did.  I think part of it has to do with your logic on the sortedPairs.Count in your while loop.  I was also getting confused by the differences between I,j,k and l.  So I rewrote your While loop using some slightly different logic.

```
    Dim currentNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim currentPositionOfNumber As Integer = 0

    While currentNumber - 1 < 8
        currentPositionOfNumber = GetIndexOfNumber(newdata, currentNumber)
        If currentNumber - 1 = currentPositionOfNumber Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf currentNumber = currentPositionOfNumber Then
            'If the number needed to move is in the spot to the immediate right of where it needs to be, then just rotate left once
            newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, currentNumber - 1, True)
            movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(1, k))
            printDebug(newdata)
        ElseIf currentPositionOfNumber = 8 Then
            'if number needed to move is in last position, then rotate it to correct position
            newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, currentNumber - 1, False)
            movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(1, k))
            printDebug(newdata)
        ElseIf currentNumber = newdata(currentPositionOfNumber + 1) - 1 Then
            'if the number is not in any of the above positions, but the number immediately to it's right is the next higher, then just rotate left until the pair are in correct position
            Do Until GetIndexOfNumber(newdata, currentNumber) = currentNumber - 1
                newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, currentNumber - 1, True)
                movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(1, k))
                printDebug(newdata)
            Loop
        Else
            'rotate left once, then rotate right to correct position
            newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, currentPositionOfNumber, True)
            movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(1, k))
            printDebug(newdata)
            newdata = CyclicRotationOffset(newdata, currentNumber - 1, False)
            movesTaken.Add(New OffsetMove(1, k))
            printDebug(newdata)
        End If
        currentNumber += 1
    End While
```

I also have a function that finds where the currentNumber being evaluated resides in the array

```
Public Function GetIndexOfNumber(data() As Byte, number As Integer) As Integer
    For i = 0 To 8
        If data(i) = number Then Return i
    Next
End Function
```

With this, I get the following results...
Test 1 = 6 Moves
Test 2 = 7 Moves

Comment: Its very nice you are a hero you really did alot of work. Problem is the last Statement with `Rotate Left, then Rotate Right`. Is wrong it doesn't give the right result Here is the debug data http://tny.cz/604ba971 I'm still glad you helped this far I may fix it up somehow, this is all very alien to me,

Comment: I can't see your debug data; just a blank screen.  What sequence are you using that you are seeing incorrect results?

Comment: Blah this is all going to be formatted wrong Original Data, Example 1
---------------------------
1, 6, 2, 0, 5, 3, 4, 7, 8 |
---------------------------

1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6 |
1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 0 |
1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 0, 5 |
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 0 |
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0, 6 |
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0  <- Didn't rotate the final bit to Offset 0 right.
If it did rotate the final bit to Offset 0 right, wouldn't that take 7 moves instead of 6?, Example 2 has the same problem with the 0

Comment: Actually, I was able to finally see your debug data.  The problem is my code above only handles numbers 1 through 9.  To correct this, the currentNumber should start at 0, but then you get out of bounds errors due to me using the number for some indexes.  My suggestion would be to do something to find the lowest number, set currentNumber to that, then run the While loop.  Of course, changes for the indexing would need done.  I assume you can handle that?

Comment: Oh, and if your final numbers are not in a sequence (i.e. 1,2,5,6,7,8 (no 3 or 4)), then the code above will not like you. :)

Comment: *** Works Properly now ***,Haha it has no missing the numbers, I just forget I started with 0 instead of 1. I'll fix it back to start from 1 again. Just a final qusetion whats the highest possible moves you think it will ever use? and which combination would that be? is it limited to 9 moves?

Comment: I love math, which is why I spent as much time as I did on this.  No, not limited to 9 moves.  Try 9,4,8,3,7,2,6,1,5

Comment: I found this pattern `6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 8` which takes 10 moves with your algorithm. Lets see what brute force will do.. I believe the optimal is 9 moves here. (Yup brute forcer found a 9 move solution.)

Comment: Here is the Brute forced answer, http://tny.cz/1f531ef4  I'll try to figure it out later this night, just letting you know. You did enough it's good enough as it is.

Comment: Yeah your example `9,4,8,3,7,2,6,1,5` takes 9 moves in your algorithm, it also takes 9 moves in the brute forcer but the next example I posted `6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 8` takes 10 moves with your algorithm and like i said it could be done in 9 moves as well http://tny.cz/1f531ef4

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LZBdMWrF  The most hardest combination is `8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 4, 1, 2` which takes 18 moves with your algorithm. The brute forcer took 15 seconds to solve it in only 9 moves haha. So I still can't tell if it possible to solve any permutation with the cyclic rotation with more then 9 moves would take brute forcer a few months to figure that out. Brute Forcer generated (Right, 5 | Right, 4 | Left, 3 | Left, 1 | Right, 2 | Left, 1 | Left, 1 | Left, 0 | Left, 1)

Comment: That combination can be solved in 7 moves actually.  (Left 5| Left 5| Left 4|Left 3|Left 2|Left 1| Left 0).  Not sure how Brute Force is working, but it seems to making some arbitrary decisions.